# Specific cron task not executing in drupal

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7

I have module, that has option to execute task on cron run. But somewhy this task isnt executing. It happened only 1 time for me, while task ran correctly. Here is code that makes my task to execute on cron run:

```
function parser_cron_queue_info() {
    $info = array();
    //  removed commented-out code
    $query = db_select('parser_jobs', 'pn')
        ->fields('pn', array('id','time_run_in_crone'))
        ->condition('run_in_crone', 1)
        ->execute();
    foreach ($query as $job){
        $info['get_parser_weather_'.$job->id] = array(
            'worker callback' => 'parser_weather',
            'time' => $job->time_run_in_crone,      
        );
    }
    return $info;
}

function parser_cron() {
    $query = db_select('parser_jobs', 'pn')
        ->fields('pn', array('id','time_run_in_crone'))
        ->condition('run_in_crone', 1)
        ->execute();
    foreach ($query as $job){
        $queue = DrupalQueue::get('get_parser_weather_'.$job->id);
        $queue->createItem($job->id);
    }
}

function  parser_weather($job_id){
    $job = parser_job_load($job_id);
    _parser_url_delete_all();
    _parser_url_add($job->start_url);
    while (_parser_url_get_not_parsed()) {
        parser_parse2($job);
    };
}
```

Any ideas whats wrong here?

P.S. After few tries of runnung cron drupal just gives me white screen of death

Comment: It's likely that your script is timing-out. What errors do your php and server logs give you?

Comment: no errors in drupal log, and instead it says that all jobs are done.

Comment: Are you running this off cron on a Unix system, or is it one of those auto-triggered pretend cron things, like Wordpress has? If the former, remember it probably runs under a different user to the web server, so it is worth checking that it has the necessary permissions to run stuff and to see the Drupal files that it needs.

Comment: Considering you don't have any print or echo statements in this code (I don't know if any of your functions print anything), white screen is the correct end-result.

Comment: Also, this code never calls any of the methods that are defined. You need to call at least one of these methods. After that call is made, just for your own double-check, have it `echo "done.";` so you know it didn't error out.

Comment: its "one of those auto-triggered pretend cron things, like Wordpress has", but in drupal 7